# multiple Numeric integral calculation lasts forever

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I'm plotting some multiple numeric integral and after 16-17 hours(i7-6700k 4.2 GHz) I didn't get the result. I tried to avoid all secondary calculations, input functions directly, disabled Symbolic Processing, made scaling of the problem so integrand value is magnitude of 1. The precision in 8 digits forced because of value of parameter $e$, function $\Sigma$ inside the integral diverges if it goes zero. If you uncomment plots before last one, you see that all functions have nice behaviour in integration region. Further I will need to integrate this again with some distribution over $p$. Any suggestions and recommendations? 
Code:

```
int = -((E^(-2 r (Sqrt[u (-4 k^2 (-1 + u) + x - y) + y] + 
      I k (1 - 2 u) Cos[θ])) (-1 + u) u (3 + 
     2 r (3 Sqrt[u (-4 k^2 (-1 + u) + x - y) + y] + 
        2 r (u (-4 k^2 (-1 + u) + x - y) + y))))/(
  2 π^3 Sqrt[
   u (-4 k^2 (-1 + u) + x - y) + 
    y] (4 k^2 (-1 + u) u - u x + (-1 + u) y)^2))
x = 1
y = 1
W[r_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Re[int]/scaleW, {u, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 8]
Σ[p_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] := 
 1/scaleΣ*(2*a^2*m^2*
     Pi*α^4*(2*
        Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
          2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

        Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
             2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                      2*k*p*Cos[θ])] + ((k^2 - (e - m)^2)^2 + 
          m^4 - 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2)*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
             2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                     2*k*p*Cos[θ]) + 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              2*k*p*Cos[θ])^2 + 

          6*m^2*(-m^2 - 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             2*k*p*Cos[θ]))/(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[θ] - 

          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                           2*k*p*Cos[θ])]) - ((k^2 - (e - 
                m)^2)^2 + m^4 - 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2)*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
             2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                     2*k*p*Cos[θ]) + 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              2*k*p*Cos[θ])^2 + 

          6*m^2*(-m^2 - 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             2*k*p*Cos[θ]))/(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[θ] + 

          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                           2*k*p*Cos[θ])]) + 
       4*(m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - k*p*Cos[θ])*

        Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          k*p*Cos[θ] - 

          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                            2*k*p*Cos[θ])]] - 
       4*(m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - k*p*Cos[θ])*

        Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          k*p*Cos[θ] + 

          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                            2*k*p*Cos[θ])]] - (1/(m^2 + (e - 
               m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[θ]))*
             ((12*m^4 - 
            8*m^2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
               2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]) + 
                   (-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
               2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[θ])^2)*
                (-Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
               k*p*Cos[θ] - 
               Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                               2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                  2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*
                Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/
                                 (-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[θ])]] + 

            Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              k*p*Cos[θ] + 

              Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

               Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                                  2*k*p*Cos[θ])]] + 
            Log[m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
              k*p*Cos[θ] - 

              Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

               Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                                  2*k*p*Cos[θ])]] - 
            Log[m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
              k*p*Cos[θ] + 

              Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

               Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                                  2*k*p*Cos[θ])]])) + (2*
           Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                           2*k*p*Cos[θ])]*(e^4 - 2*e^2*k^2 + 
             k^4 - 4*e^3*m + 4*e*k^2*m + 8*e^2*m^2 - 4*k^2*m^2 - 
             8*e*m^3 + m^4 - 
                     4*e^3*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             4*e*k^2*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 12*e^2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             4*k^2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                     6*e*m^2*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*m^3*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 9*e^2*(m^2 + p^2) - 
             18*e*m*(m^2 + p^2) + 9*m^2*(m^2 + p^2) - 
                     4*e^2*k*p*Cos[θ] + 
             4*k^3*p*Cos[θ] + 8*e*k*m*p*Cos[θ] + 
             2*k*m^2*p*Cos[θ] + 
             18*e*k*p*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]*Cos[θ] - 
                     18*k*m*p*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]*Cos[θ] + 
             9*k^2*p^2*
              Cos[θ]^2 - (e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 
                2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                          2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                2*k*p*Cos[θ])*(-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*
                    Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - k*p*Cos[θ])^2/
                            (-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                   2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   2*k*p*Cos[θ]))) + 
          4*(m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - k*p*Cos[θ])*
                  (m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             k*p*Cos[θ] - 

             Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

              Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                   2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                                2*k*p*Cos[θ])])*(m^2 + 
             e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             k*p*Cos[θ] + 

             Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

              Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                   2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                                2*k*p*Cos[θ])])*(-Log[
               m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
                k*p*Cos[θ] - 

                Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                   2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

                 Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                                    2*k*p*Cos[θ])]] + 
             Log[m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
               k*p*Cos[θ] + 

               Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                  2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

                Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*
                                    Cos[θ])]]))/((m^2 + 
            e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
            k*p*Cos[θ] - 

            Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
               2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

             Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                  2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                              2*k*p*Cos[θ])])*(m^2 + 
            e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
            k*p*Cos[θ] + 

            Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
               2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[θ]]*

             Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   k*p*Cos[θ])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                  2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                              2*k*p*Cos[θ])]))))/((-k^2 + (e - 
          m)^2 - 3*m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
       2*k*p*Cos[θ])*
        (-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
       2*k*p*Cos[θ]))

m = 0.5109989461
α = 1/137
e = (α^2 m)/2
a = 1/(α*m)
scaleΣ = 10^6
scaleW = 10^-3
(*Plot[Σ[p=0.5,k/a,θ=0],{k,0,5}]
Plot[Σ[p,1/a,θ=0],{p,0.05,1.1}]
Plot[Σ[p=0.5,1/a,θ],{θ,0,Pi}]
Plot3D[r^2*k^2*W[r,k,θ=0],{r,0,5},{k,0,5},PlotRange\[Rule]All,\
AxesLabel\[Rule]Automatic]
Plot3D[r^2*k^2*W[r,k,θ=Pi/2],{r,0,5},{k,0,5},PlotRange\[Rule]\
All,AxesLabel\[Rule]Automatic]*)
Plot[(*scaleΣ*scaleW*2Pi*a^-2**)
 NIntegrate[Σ[p, k/a, θ]*W[r, k, θ]*
   Sin[θ]*k^2, {θ, 0, Pi}, {k, 0, 5}, {r, 0, 5}, 
  Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 8], {p, 0.055, 1.1}]
Clear[x, y, int, W, k, r, θ, c, u, m, e, a, p, σ, \
Σ, t1, t0, M, t, s]
```

**Edit:**
I noticed that integral can be done analytically by $r$ so integration dimension reduces to 3. Now it looks like $\int_{0}^{5}\int_{0}^{\pi}\Sigma(p,k,\theta)\int_0^1duf(k,\theta,u)dkd\theta$. It can be done numerically one time by $u$ and I plotted integrand by $k$ and $\theta$ with fixed $p$. It is still very smooth function and should be simple to plot over $p$ but it does not. I have removed precision requirements and decreased digits in $m$. Computation in a fixed $p$ required about 100 sec. 
For $p=0.5$ I got `{100.716, 22.1118}`. Any estimates how much time I need to wait to get plot over $p$?

```
f[k_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := 
 Re[-(1/(scaleW*2 \[Pi]^3 (1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u)^(5/2))) (-1 + 
     u) u* (-((-16 + 3 k^2 - 76 k^2 u + 76 k^2 u^2 + 
       18 I k (-1 + 2 u) Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] Cos[\[Theta]] + 
       3 k^2 (1 - 2 u)^2 Cos[2 \[Theta]])/(
      4 (Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] - 
         I k (-1 + 2 u) Cos[\[Theta]])^3)) + 
     E^(-10 Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] + 
       10 I k (-1 + 2 u) Cos[\[Theta]]) ((
        50 I (-1 + 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u))/(
        I Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] + k (-1 + 2 u) Cos[\[Theta]]) + (
        5 (5 (-1 + 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u) + 
           3 I k (-1 + 2 u) Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u]
             Cos[\[Theta]]))/(Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] - 
          I k (-1 + 2 u) Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (-16 + 3 k^2 - 76 k^2 u + 
         76 k^2 u^2 + 
         18 I k (-1 + 2 u) Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         3 k^2 (1 - 2 u)^2 Cos[2 \[Theta]])/(
        4 (Sqrt[1 - 4 k^2 (-1 + u) u] - 
           I k (-1 + 2 u) Cos[\[Theta]])^3)))]
\[CapitalSigma][p_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ] := 
 1/scale\[CapitalSigma]*(2*a^2*m^2*
     Pi*\[Alpha]^4*(2*
        Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
          2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
        Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
             2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])] + ((k^2 - (e - m)^2)^2 + m^4 - 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2)*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
             2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]) + 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + 
          6*m^2*(-m^2 - 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]))/(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]) - ((k^2 - (e - m)^2)^2 + m^4 - 

          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2)*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
             2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]) + 
          2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + 
          6*m^2*(-m^2 - 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]))/(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]) + 
       4*(m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])*
        Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]] - 
       4*(m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])*
        Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
          k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
          Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]] - (1/(m^2 + (e - m)*
             Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]))*((12*m^4 - 
            8*m^2*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
               2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
               2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]) + (-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
               2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
               2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2)*(-Log[-m^2 - 
               e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
               k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
               Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                  2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
                Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]] + 

            Log[-m^2 - e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
              k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
              Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
               Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]] + 
            Log[m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
              k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
              Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
               Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]] - 
            Log[m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
              k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
              Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
               Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]])) + (2*
           Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
             2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
           Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                 k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]*(e^4 - 2*e^2*k^2 + k^4 - 
             4*e^3*m + 4*e*k^2*m + 8*e^2*m^2 - 4*k^2*m^2 - 8*e*m^3 + 
             m^4 - 4*e^3*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 4*e*k^2*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             12*e^2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 4*k^2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             6*e*m^2*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*m^3*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
             9*e^2*(m^2 + p^2) - 18*e*m*(m^2 + p^2) + 
             9*m^2*(m^2 + p^2) - 4*e^2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
             4*k^3*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 8*e*k*m*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
             2*k*m^2*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
             18*e*k*p*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
             18*k*m*p*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
             9*k^2*p^2*
              Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - (e^2 - k^2 - 2*m^2 + 
                2*m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*
                    Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                   2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]))) + 
          4*(m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])*(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
             Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
              Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                   2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])])*(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
             m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
             Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
              Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                   2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])])*(-Log[
               m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
                k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
                Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                   2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
                 Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]] + 
             Log[m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
               k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
               Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
                  2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
                Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                    2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                    2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]]))/((m^2 + 
            e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + 
            k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
            Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
               2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
             Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                  2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                  2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])])*(m^2 + e*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
            m*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + k*p*Cos[\[Theta]] + 
            Sqrt[e^2 - k^2 + 2*m*(-m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 
               2*e*(m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
             Sqrt[-m^2 + (m^2 + (-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                   k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])^2/(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
                  2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
                  2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])]))))/((-k^2 + (e - m)^2 - 
       3*m^2 + 2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 
       2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-k^2 + (e - m)^2 + m^2 + 
       2*(-e + m)*Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - 2*k*p*Cos[\[Theta]]))
m = 0.5109
\[Alpha] = 1/137
e = (\[Alpha]^2 m)/2
a = 1/(\[Alpha]*m)
scale\[CapitalSigma] = 10^6
scaleW = 10^-3
Plot3D[Sin[\[Theta]]*k^2*\[CapitalSigma][p = 0.5, k/a, \[Theta]]*
  NIntegrate[f[k, \[Theta], u], {u, 0, 1}], {k, 0, 5}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
NIntegrate[(*scale\[CapitalSigma]*scaleW*2Pi*
  a^-2*)\[CapitalSigma][p = 0.5, k/a, \[Theta]]*f[k, \[Theta], u]*
   Sin[\[Theta]]*k^2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {k, 0, 5}, {u, 0, 
   1}] // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[NIntegrate[(*scale\[CapitalSigma]*scaleW*2Pi*
  a^-2*)\[CapitalSigma][p, k/a, \[Theta]]*f[k, \[Theta], u]*
   Sin[\[Theta]]*k^2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {k, 0, 5}, {u, 0, 1}], {p, 
  0.05, 1.1}]
Clear[x, y, int, W, k, r, \[Theta], c, u, m, e, a, p, \[Sigma], \
\[CapitalSigma], t1, t0, M, t, s, f, \[Alpha]]
```

Comment: have you got that `NIntegrate` to evaluate at all? If it works at all you should generate a table over p and use `ListPlot`. You can often get a reasonable plot with far fewer evaluations than `Plot` will need.

Comment: I tried to calculate it in a single point instead of plotting and it still running for about 40 mins... for single point... Tomorrow I will update my question, looks like things are going really bad.

Comment: You have this options `PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 8` -- no wonder your computations are slow. Use machine precision for faster results. To start investigating, how quickly you get results with `PrecisionGoal -> 2, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` ?

Comment: @AntonAntonov The value of parameter $e$ is 10^-6. If precision is too small this will be zero and function $\Sigma$ inside the integral diverges

Comment: do you realize `WorkingPrecision->8` is much smaller precision than default? What you are saying about singularity makes no sense. That said the integral doesn't evaluate in any reasonable time at `MachinePrecision` either.

Comment: My bad, I thought default value is 4 digits and $e$ will be rounded to zero. I didn't notice `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision`